# Example of matrices with eigen values $\lambda=\sqrt{t}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I'm looking for an example of 2x2 matrices $A$, $B$ such that for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ the matrix
$$C = A+tB$$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2}=\pm\sqrt{t}$, I've tried but I got always $\lambda_{1,2}=\pm t$

Comment: What do you mean by $\lambda_{1,2}=\sqrt{t}$? Do you want both eigenvalues to be equal to $\sqrt{t}$?

Comment: Sorry my bad, edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider
\begin{align}
M =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
t & 0
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}+
t
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, now I realize my error was not zeroed the other value of the second diagonal for the B matrix.